# IIS 8 - HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: http

I try to run web site on IIS8 but it says:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

The web.config should be ok.
How to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable "detailed errors" from **IIS Manager** >> Double Click on your **website** >> click on **Error pages** >> click on "**edit features settings**" >> select "**detailed errors**" >> **Save**.